# swiftUI and HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: ios, swiftui, http-live-streaming

I am looking to set up a live stream within my swiftUI app. I have looked at Apple's HTTP Live Streaming example on their website, but am having trouble converting that to swiftUI code (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/using_avfoundation_to_play_and_persist_http_live_streams)

I have already implemented the ability to play a video in swiftUI from a local file.

Any suggestions on how to play live stream from server in my swiftUI app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an online live stream provider to host your video you could create a web view using WebKit to display a website. Simply put you can create a view that displays a website. The limitations of this that it won't look very nice depending on how you configure it and the user will most likely have to press play to start the stream.

A  great tutorial would be this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C5xxrCj8LC0&t

Code I used in my personal program using this tutorial:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct Webview: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var url: String
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    
        guard let url = URL(string: self.url) else {
            return WKWebView()
        }
        
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    let wkWebview = WKWebView()
    wkWebview.load(request)
    return wkWebview
    
    
}

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: Webview.UIViewType, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Webview>) {
        
        
    }
}
```

You display the view by calling it with: `Webview(url: "The url you wish to display")`

Overall, not sure about your exact intentions but this might be able to work for you.